# ASP.net Web API's ActionFilterAttribute throws InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

In our production environment some users cannot login through our Web API because the following exception is thrown on the server side:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__1.MoveNext()
```

I cannot figure out how to reproduce this on the development environment. The error message is also very unclear and there's nothing from our code in the stack trace.

Have any of you experienced this issue? What could possibly cause it?

Comment: is it a custom action filter? if so what is the code in it?

Comment: what do you mean with "it"? The request should reach the ``LoginControlller``'s method with the following signature: "``[HttpPost] public HttpResponseMessage PostLogin([FromBody] LoginRequest login)``"

Comment: Could you please post your api controller code and what you are trying to do from script

Comment: The code is too complex to post here, cause it calls methods from other assemblies via dependency injection. However I think I found the problem by searching for all Single() calls in the whole solution. Terrible that the stack trace couldn't give me any info whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Spent half a day on this, found the cause, In the owin appbuilder chain `app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);` was called twice. This results in two similair AuthenticationResults resulting in a Sequence contains more than one element.

Answer (score -3):

This error occurs when the collection doesn't contain exactly 0 or 1 elements and you are using `.SingleOrDefault()`.

Use `.FirstOrDefault()` instead.

Comment: I already mentioned that in my comment, so there's no point in responding the question with such information. The problem was the incorrect stack trace

Comment: Yes, you mentioned it, but you didn't give an explanation as to what the cause of the problem was, nor a solution. If you read the first line, you'll see that it tells you exactly what the problem was: "Sequence contains more than one element".

Comment: It also tells me that the problem was in classes of the .NET framework, which makes me think it wasn't a bug in our code.